# When splitting 1 service into multiple services, do the configurations for the service need split and each part stored in the services?

Tags: web-services, design-patterns, service, architecture, microservices

Let's say you have a "monolith" with a set of configurations

```
{
    id: 1273,
    fooConfig: { .. },
    barConfig: { .. },
    bazConfig: { ...}
}
```

and you want to split it into `Foo`, `Bar` and `Baz` services which run jobs when asked to by a central workflow engine.

Do you need to store each of the configurations in the services, like

```
// Foo service config (stored in Foo service)
{
   id: 1273,
   .
   .  // fooConfig stuff
   .
} 

// Bar service config (stored in Bar service)
{
   id: 1273,
   .
   .  // barConfig stuff
   .
} 

// Baz service config (stored in Baz service)
{
   id: 1273,
   .
   .  // bazConfig stuff
   .
}
```

or can you store the configuration in some other service (say `Configuration Manager` service) and input the respective parts of it into the 3 job services when they are invoked?

Comment: can you give an example of white kind of configuration fields you are referring to?

Answer (score 0):

You can save at common place. There is actually pattern called **External Configuration Store.** . The idea is to save configuration at central location and access as needed. It's easy and if tomorrow you add more services you can imagine the benefits . You can find more about here [External Configuration Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/external-configuration-store)